# java.lang.Long cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn I don't understend why I recive this

Tags: clojure

```
(def text1 "qwwqer qwasdfas")
(defn countL [text char] (reduce 0
                                 #(if (= %2 char) (+ %1 1) (+ %1 0))
                                 text)
)
(println (countL text1 "q"))
```

I write this code and recive this error, but I not understand why? Please explain to me.

Comment: You have wrong arguments order. you need `(reduce f val coll)` . So, `0` is not a function obviously. Just swap them.

Comment: Ohh realy, not watch this... But now I have new problem, why all time I recive 0.

Comment: because your reducing function operates on *chars*, while you pass to `countL` a string. so `char q` != "q". Just call `(countL text1 \q)`

Comment: it can really be much simpler: `(count (filter #(= % \q) text1))` or even `(count (filter #{\q} text1))`

Comment: u may explain me why work second variant? `(count (filter #{\q} text1))` ??

Comment: @NickitaDavidenko Which part of that do you need explained? Sets can be treated as functions, in which case they return true if their argument is part of the set, or false if it isn't. Filter is using it as a predicate to filter out all non-"q"s, then counts the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument order for reduce is incorrect.
See https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reduce